# Firebase realtime DB fetch ids

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase realtime data structure like on picture. How to get only items with same id value? There can be lot of items under same item number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolve issue by changing structure, removed numbers subitems, and add id of user into last subitem